# Using PERCENTILE.INC funciton on multiple ranges (combine arrays)

Tags: arrays, vba, percentile

I am trying to use the PERCENTILE.INC on multiple ranges (specifically two ranges).  However I am having a difficult time combining the ranges into one array.  I have read up on a few sites on how to combine ranges, but this doesn't appear to work for me.  A VBA or non VBA solution would suffice.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer.  There are many many postings on this, however, I only found one solution that actually worked:

http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/404908-morefunc-array-join-alternative.html